# Segmentation fault and getter issue

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, getter

i have an assignment that tracks persons, and for now i need to make the crud operations. 
When i try to access the dynamic array, the getter for person's id works, but the one for persons phone returns "segmentation fault", and the one for person's name shows nothing.

```
//the main.cpp test that gives the following error
Controller ctrl(repp,repa,valp,vala);
ctrl.addPerson(1,"Name","0744000000","Adress");     
ctrl.show();

//controller show method, repp - instance of repository in controler
void Controller::show()
{
    repp->show();
}

//repository show method, which doesn't work
void PersonInMemoryRepository::show()
{
    for(int i=0; i < pers.getSize(); i++)
        cout<<pers.get(i)->getName()<<endl;
}

//getById method in repository
const Person* PersonInMemoryRepository::getById(int id)
{
for (int i = 0; i < pers.getSize(); i++) 
    {
    if (pers.get(i)->getId() == id) {
        return pers.get(i);
                                    }
}
return NULL;
}

 //the Person class
 class Person 
 {
 public:
Person(int i, string n, string p, string a);
const string& getName() const {
    return name;
}
const string& getPhone() const {
    return phone;
}
const string& getAdress() const {
    return adress;
    }
int getId() const {
    return id;
}
    ~Person();
 private:
    int id;
string name;
string phone;
string adress;
};
//pers.get(i)
template<typename Element>
Element DynamicArray<Element>::get(int poz) {
return elems[poz];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Update: When it's on the line cout<getName(); . pers.get(i) works good, it's a Person* type vector, and when i dereference it in the debugger, it has the right values,  but at the ->getName() it says "invalid number 0 of repetitions".

Comment: The first thing you should do when you get a "segmentation fault" (or any type of crash for that matter) is to run the application in a debugger. This will help you pinpoint the location of the crash, and also let you examine variables to see what might cause it.

Comment: trying hard to understand the code but too many gaps.

Comment: When the first thing failed, the second thing you should do when you get a "segmentation fault" (or any type of crash for that matter) is to properly indent your code _before_ hitting the submit button.

Comment: I have no ideea how to debug :|. It doesn't work like in the youtube tutorials. Ps: i m using code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

While you have not showen enough code to understand the problem completly assuming that pers is some form of container from the standard library most size functions give results for the size of the number of elements starting their count from one while element access for the container starts at zero. This means that to correctly access all the elements you need to subtract one from the size of the container.

If this assumption is true the correct code for a for loop is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pers.getSize()-1; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you show is insufficient to figure out what is causing the seg. fault.  My guess would be that you overindex into the `elems` container (maybe the `pers.getSize()` returns the wrong value?)

Comment: pers.getSize() returns the correct value. Anyway, the pers.get(i)->getId() , return the correct id(which is int), so i think it's pointing in the right place. Maybe the way i declared the getters could be a problem? . I tryed some other ways but none worked.

Comment: If you are sure you only access valid indices into `pers`, the only remaining possibility I can think of is that you overindex into some other array that corrupts data in `pers`.

Comment: Is there a way i can upload all the code, and maybe someone will help me?! . And i have no other array or methods that can affect the indexing. It's just an add and show.

Comment: If all the code is not too long, you can edit the question to include the parts you left out; otherwise you could try some external sites (like pastebin.com) to hold your code, however it is a better idea to narrow the code dow as much as possible while keeping it to reproduce the problem.  Also, you should learn how to debug, otherwise you will have a very hard time finding/fixing bugs

Comment: Ok, i 've just figure out how to use the debugger. When it's on the line cout<<pers.get(i)->getName(); .  pers.get(i) works  good, but on the ->getName() it says "invalid number 0 of repetitions" . The pointer this , is filled with the right values, i don t know if it matters.

Comment: The Person::getName() function you listed cannot fail if the Person object returned by pers.get(i) is valid.  What is the definition of DynamicArray<>::elems?  What is the value of i when the error happens?

Comment: @Atilla . I've pasted all the dynamic array code here. Anyway, i've debugged the program again, and the pers.get(i), isn t valid anymore.  http://pastebin.com/EDDVixWm

Comment: I have looked at the dynamic array code and it looks OK to me.  I have also put together a compilable program based on the bits and pieces you presented, tried your three-line main test and the program executed without a problem.  It looks like you are doing more than what you have shared so far.  I suggest you put together a (small) program that demonstrates the problematic behavior (as consistently as you can) and update your question.  Make a copy of your actual project and start stripping it down taking away parts whithout wich the program still has the erroneous behavior

Comment: Thank you very much, i will follow your advice.